# Import Windows 11 emoji emoticones into windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, windows-11, emoji

https://emojipedia.org/troll/ is not available in windows 10, but it is in windows 11. My company laptop will update once my IT team will decide it's time.
Meanwhile, how can I import the new w11 emoji in w10 without upgrading to w11 ?

Thanks

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WBQ6aW7P9rY

Comment: Emoticon support requires underline operating system support. So what you want is not possible until Microsoft updates the version of Emoticon(s) it supports on Windows 10.

Comment: @Moab I followed the tutorial but that does not add missing emoji to my W10. I only see the existing emoji with a new look in the emoji picker. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Ramhound is it possible to add the .dll or the windows underlying brick that manages the emoji render ? or is it built in deeply in the rendering processes ?

Comment: @Poutrathor - You could try but you likely would run into a game of whack a mole with regards to dependencies.  I just know iOS, Android, macOS, and Windows all have to recieve updates to update the version of emoticon that are supported..

Comment: can you point me to the first mole to whack ? I will see where it goes from there.